# Sign-in dialog box for third party website

Tags: javascript, java

I need to develop a modal login which will be used on some other website. The log in modal dialog will interact with rest API in the back for successful and failed login.

This is something similar to facebook or google sign-in on any website.
What combination of technologies can be used.
I have good experience in java but don't have experience in node.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your reasoning for including Java as a tag? Are you using a Java framework? Same with JavaScript? (Oh, and welcome to the site.)

Comment: Included Java/Javascript tag so that people from this community can suggest some answer as i'm really looking some java framework solution

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not meant as a forum to ask for suggestions. It's for code that you have tried to write but is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Companies like Facebook and Google use [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/) to authenticate and communicate with external websites. OAuth can be implemented on a few different technology stacks as well:

- PHP
- Java
- NodeJS
- Ruby
- .NET
- Python
- Erlang